# How to fill empty array with "for loop" and "prompt(' ')" in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, prompt

I have written:

```js
var arr = [];
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var name = prompt('please, enter your name');
    arr.push(name);
}

console.log(arr);
```

But it is does not work. It asks me only once, but I need to make array with five names.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem

Comment: Yes it works perfectly

Comment: Is that the real code? You would get the behavior you describe if you have the `prompt` call before the loop, and `push` inside the loop.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Works fine in chrome

Comment: Maybe in your actual code you call not prompt but modal and your loop ends while first popup is shown?

Comment: sorry, it is maybe bug in jsbin.com

Comment: Or maybe you've clicked that checkbox on the popup prompt that says "stop this page from showing additional dialogs" (or something close to that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me. Are you using Google Chrome to test. Maybe something for above it is interrupting. Try it on a new Javascript File. If you're using Chrome to test what is the log saying Ctrl + Shift + J let me know.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It works ok, it is maybe bug in jsbin.com. Sorry.

Comment: It's not a bug - check the dev tools console: it explicitly explains what is happening.